# Guardar y recuperar una lista al rotar el dispositivo en Java de Android

Tags: java, android

Tengo un `List<Sendero>` que se puebla de una base de datos, quiero evitar la recarga de datos de la base de datos cuando el dispositivo rota

Es decir quiero guardar la lista para así recuperarla en `onCreate` usando `savedInstanceState`

**Para guardar**

El mismo Android-Studio me genera el siguiente código:

```
private List<Route> listData;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("list_data", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) listData);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

El problema viene a la hora de recuperar, me indica un warning.

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
   listData = (List<Route>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("list_data");
}
```

Warning siguiente:

```
Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable'  to  'java.util.List<app.....models.Route>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que es correcto lo que realizas al salvar y recuperar la Lista pero tu objeto debe implementar [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) :

```
public class Route implements Parcelable {
```

Answer (score 1):

Incluir esto en tu if debería de servir(Bueno, yo pondria la lista como variable de clase):

```
ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> listData;

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
  listData = ( ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>)   savedInstanceState.getSerializable("list_data");
}
```

Comment: He modificado un poco la pregutna ya que he encontrado la manera pero me indica un warning